# Is it possible to deploy JSF MyFaces 1.1.5 applications to TomEE

Tags: jsf, myfaces, apache-tomee

With Tomcat7 i can deploy several application with misced use of MyFaces 1.x / 2.x 
In TomEE i run to many exceptions if i deploy Applications with MyFaces 1.x, because tomee has builtin myfaces2 support..
Any ideas, is there a possibility to switch of modules like in jboss?

Answer (score 0):

Should work fine.  Just delete the myfaces-*.jars from `<tomcat-home>/lib/` and then include the desired MyFaces jars in each webapp.

Comment: What if TomEE is outside developer's control or if disabling needs to be done on a per-webapp basis? JBoss AS for example offers a `web.xml` context parameter `org.jboss.jbossfaces.WAR_BUNDLES_JSF_IMPL` to turn off loading of container-provided JSF on a per-webapp basis. TomEE might consider to do the same in order to be less primitive.

Comment: We're a bit limited by the fact Tomcat controls all classloading.  We've had some ideas on that such as not adding the MyFaces/JSF libraries in the Tomcat system classloader by in some way excluding them from <tomcat-home>/lib/, then conditionally include them in the WebappClassLoader depending on whether or not the webapp already has those things.  The downside of this approach is it would break tooling like the Eclipse Tomcat Plugin -- would effectively make JSF not available as an API jar.