# Howto deploy a JSF 1.2 application to TomEE 1.7.1?

Tags: jsf-1.2, apache-tomee

I tried to deploy an application with JSF 1.2 to TomEE 1.7.1 Web Profile and of course got exceptions because of the JSF 2.0-Libs in TomEE ... .

According to the article [Is it possible to deploy JSF MyFaces 1.1.5 applications to TomEE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515424/is-it-possible-to-deploy-jsf-myfaces-1-1-5-applications-to-tomee) I removed the following libs from the TomEE lib dir:
- myfaces-api-2.1.15.jar
- myfaces-impl-2.1.15.jar

When starting the application I get:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/application/ApplicationWrapper
```

Is there any way to disable JSF 2.x support per application?